# How can foldMap do the same as foldr when the latter does not have anything to do with monoids?

Tags: haskell, fold, monoids

[`foldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) and [`foldMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap) can be used to define each other as I understand. But how is that possible, as the latter uses monoids, while the former does not? Do we have any guarantees that the stuff the `foldr` works on can have a monoid?

Comment: You might want to read [Tom Ellis' "What is `foldr` made of?"](http://web.jaguarpaw.co.uk/~tom/blog/posts/2012-11-04-what-is-foldr-made-of.html) and [Brent Yorgey's response "`foldr` is made of monoids"](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/foldr-is-made-of-monoids/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Note that `a -> b -> b` is `a -> (b -> b)`. Functions `b -> b` form a monoid under composition.

Note how this resembles

```
foldMap :: (..omitted..) => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
```

The only difference is that foldMap doesn't use the "zero" argument of type `b` of `fold` and returns an `m`, which in terms of `foldr` would be `b->b`. Now just apply one to the other and you've recovered `foldr` from `foldMap`.